# conversion from void* to char*

Tags: c++, c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    void *malloc(size_t size);
    char *ptr, *retval;
    ptr = (char *)calloc(10, sizeof(char));

    if (ptr == NULL)
        printf("calloc failed\n");
    else
        printf("calloc successful\n");

    retval = realloc(ptr, 5);

    if (retval == NULL)
        printf("realloc failed\n");
    else
        printf("realloc successful\n");

    free(ptr);
    free(retval);
}
```

here is my code the error arises at line 14, it says

> invalid conversion from "void*" to "char*"

Comment: This is not C++, so don't tag it as such.

Comment: Can you reformat this so it reads cleaner?

Comment: @Xeo: If it was being compiled as C he wouldn't get the issue ... So C++ is probably more apt ...

Comment: @Goz: If he knew what he was doing, he'd compile it as C. :P

Comment: @Xeo: No doubt ;) ... but his problem arises because he is writing C++ code (whether he realises it or not) ... as such the c++ tag is more apt than the C tag (IMO and all that)

Comment: @jamesdlin: Nice one on remembering to change the line number ;)

Comment: I've reverted the tag to C++, because this is specifically a C++ problem, even if the code could be compiled as C.

Comment: To the people edit-warring over the tags: this is unquestionably a question about C++.  This issue can **only** happen when compiling as C++.  Whether the C tag should *also* be included is debatable (I'd lean towards leaving it in, since this highlights an important difference between the two languages), but the C++ tag absolutely applies.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could just caast the result of the realloc to (char*) like you do with the malloc.

```
retval = (char*)realloc(ptr, 5);
```

Ironically though what you have written is perfectly legal "C" code ... just not C++ where you require the cast.  So you might also try setting your compiler to compile the code as "C" as you aren't doing any C++ and that would equally solve the issue.  That said the above modification is also perfectly legal C ... so would compile under C++ and C.

Edit: As softy rightly points out you realloc ptr and store the pointer location into retval which means that ptr is, potentially, pointing at invalid memory and you should NOT free it.  At best you free the same memory twice, at worst you call free on memory that has already been freed (by realloc).  Either way it is bad (tm). As it is you are invoking some serious "undefined behaviour".

Comment: well!!thanks for your answers. anyways i have done it :) and the sorry about the tags as it was my first question so i didn't know how to use em ;) thanks anyways ;)

Comment: @ejazdogar:  If you click the little tick under the number to the left of my post then you "accept" my post ;)

Answer (score 1):

You cant free a pointer twice.Here the  retval and ptr both points to the same location 
add this code and check before free call :

```
printf("%p \n ",ptr);
printf("%p \n",retval);
```

realloc has shrunk teh size but the pointer location remains the same.
you may try this as well :

```
if(ptr == retval)

/* delete either ptr or retval - just for sake of this programm , Idealy you shouldnt free the the pointer like this as Rightly Suggested by **Goz** in C++/c*/
```

Just to make it work.otherwise it compiles fine by gcc but if you run it will give a dirty stack trace as you are trying to free the same pointer twice.the underlying break call by the memory allocation function may or may not assign the same pointer to it .IF you expand teh size may be by 30 or 50 it may give you different pointer .

rgds,
Softy

Comment: You have a good point but after reallocing you absoloutely must not, ever, free ptr ... it either points to the same location as retval or has already been freed!

Comment: yes it may or may not that's why that ptr equivalence check !

Comment: but if they aren't equal (or even if they are) then you shouldn't free ptr ... so the equivalence check is immaterial ... calling free on ptr is an error waiting to happen ...

Comment: ralloc does not need to shrink the space it may give back completely different memory. `if (retval != NULL) {ptr = retval;}`

Answer (score 1):

Others have noted that your C code is being compiled as C++ code.  The cast is unnecessary in C, but is required in C++.  In C++, you should use vectors (or string).

Here are some observations on your code:

1. Do not redeclare malloc.  Including stdlib.h will do that for you.  Thankfully you have duplicated its declaration successfully, so it is only redundant (and confusing to someone else reading the code).  If you got the declaration wrong, you have undefined behaviour.
2. Do not free 'ptr' if realloc is successful.
3. Some folks may point out that, in some esoteric systems, calloc may not do what you expect (specifically for pointer and floating point types).  Considering that you'd want your dynamically allocated space to be initialised with suitable values anyway, it is superfluous to call calloc than malloc.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to compile, use C compilation.  It looks as if you are using C++ compilation.  It is valid C but not valid C++.  In most compilers using a lowercase .c extension will cause the compiler to use C compilation automatically.  .cpp will cause C++ compilation, also .C (uppercase) may cause C++ compilation (in gcc for example).